# Split mongodb nested array into multiple documents

Tags: mongodb

I have the following Mongodb document

```
{
"name":"test",
"events":[{"type":"test","date":"2020-04-01"}], //Has 100,000 entries
"note":"test"
}
```

How can i split this document into multiple documents holding a max of 1,000 entries. This would look like this

```
{
"name":"test",
"events":[{"type":"test","date":"2020-04-01"}], //Has first 1000 entries
"note":"test"
}
{
    "name":"test",
    "events":[{"type":"test","date":"2020-05-01"}], //Has the next 1000 entries
    "note":"test"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use mongodb [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/).

To separate data in arrays use [unwind operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/). This gives you a collection of documents where the "unwinded" array has one document only. Then you can group them together (maybe by date?) and use [push operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) to put again in an array.

You can also use [slice operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) to "slice" an array in a subset of elements.

**Note**: I think an array of more than 100000 elements is really "big" and you should consider to use also [allowDiskUse](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.allowDiskUse/) option

Comment: Thank you. How do i slice events to a max of 1,000 elements each

Comment: Like I've written, try to use an aggregation, unwind and then group/push and slice. I'm not able to provide a running example without a proper input. As idea, why not unwind and then group by date? Result will not be exactly 1000 elements, but then you can process them